# Is there a way to use selenium in combination with the Opera GX Browser?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, url

I'm trying to get the current page url on my Opera GX browser, but I can't find if there is a way to do it. I thought selenium might work, but when I run my code, it gives me this in the command prompt:

```
[12252:21468:0914/190450.397:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome://startpage/ (0)
```

The output error in the python IDE is this one:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Opera failed to start: exited normally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from opera location C:/Users/remis/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/launcher.exe is no longer running, so OperaDriver is assuming that Opera has crashed.)
(Driver info: operadriver=84.0.4147.89 (19abfe7bcba9318a0b2a6bc6634a67fc834aa592-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#852}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Users/remis/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/launcher.exe"
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path="C:/Users/remis/PycharmProjects/FormationChecker/operadriver_win64/operadriver.exe", options = options)
print(driver.current_url)
time.sleep(1)
```

I'm very new to selenium and this is just a very simple test. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Hey @Vynokris, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: No I didn't sorry but it seems opera gx isn't supported by a lot of programmers

Answer (score 0):

opera gx is not supported by selenium the only browsers available rn are : Chrome, internet explorer(edge), firefox and safari